# Mails send with SwiftMailer not using style blocks

Tags: php, css, email, swiftmailer, zurb-ink

I'm trying to send HTML formatted emails using Zurb Ink template and SwiftMailer. But when I recieve the mail in my inbox all the formatting that was defined in a `<style></style>` block is removed. I have added to the `text/html` content-type like so: `$message->setBody("HTML HERE", 'text/html');` When I recieve the email all the formatting is removed.

Is this an issue with SwiftMailer or am I missing a configuration value?

Comment: What mail client do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some mail clients will hide styled emails unless you choose to view it as HTML. And certain web mail clients and mail providers will ignore internal stylesheets. You can however use inline style. Example:

```
<font color="red">This is red</font>
```

or

```
<a style="color: #333333;">link</a>
```

Comment: Will the inline styling always be used if the mail is viewed as HTML? Or are there cases where these inline styles also are being ignored?

Comment: Yes, inline styling will always be used when viewing as html provided with correct html tags and I have never encountered where the styles were ignored ... yet. Normally exchange servers allow stylesheets